# MYSQL Change the host of the users using RENAME and a variable with the values

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, hardening

I create a procedure to try to change host wildcard into 'localhost' but It return me an error when process the host [error with wildcard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECBfk.png)

This is my code

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE wildcardprocedure()
BEGIN
DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE a CHAR(50);
DECLARE o CHAR(20);

DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT user FROM user WHERE Host='%';

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done=1;

OPEN cur1;

REPEAT

  FETCH cur1 INTO o;
  SELECT @a:= CONCAT(o,'@localhost');
  RENAME USER '@o' TO '@a';

UNTIL done END REPEAT;

CLOSE cur1;
END//
```

I need to check what users are using a wildcard, save the list of users in a variable and them RENAME USER to change the Host in a loop and schedule it with event_schedule.

I tried an [easy form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfLEp.png) but It doesn't work UPDATE mysql.user set Host=localhost where Host='%';

Thanks!!

Comment: User-defined variables names won't replace with their values. SQL is not PHP. You must use prepared statement.

Comment: *I create a procedure to try to change host wildcard into 'localhost'* You'll damage all existing roles.